# Wildcard for filenames in Nginx location path

Tags: nginx

E.g. Load only all `.png` files in the directory if they have a keyword `apple-` and skip if they don't.

E.g. we have:

```
location ~* \.(?:png|xml|ico|svg|webmanifest)$ {
    alias /var/www/site.com/htdocs/sites/all/themes/dev/img/favicons;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    expires     365d;
    add_header  ETag "";
    add_header  Pragma public;
    add_header  Cache-Control "max-age=31449600, no-transform, public";
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
```

But that takes all `.png` files. So e.g. something like `|apple-*.png|` doesn't work. Need this because there's a dozen of `apple-touch-icon.png` and `apple-touch-icon-76x76.png` and so on... files that needs to be loaded from same directory, but skip others.

Comment: @RichardSmith it doesn't work `location ~* \.(?:apple-[^/]+\.png$|xml|ico|svg|webmanifest)$ { ` and without `$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression `apple-*.png` matches filenames with lots of hyphens (e.g. `apple------.png`). The `*` means *zero or more of the preceding character*.

You could use `.*` to match zero or more of any character, or `[^/]+` to match at least one character which is not a `/`.

For example:

```
location ~* apple-[^/]+\.png$ { ... }
```

---

To apply that constraint to `.png` files, but also allow other extensions (without the constraint), use:

```
location ~* apple-[^/]+\.png$|\.(xml|ico|svg|webmanifest)$ { ... }
```